# Algebraic question

Tags: linear-algebra

I've been trying to solve this question for the past few hours with no luck, I'm starting to feel a formula may be involved. Can you please help me out on this problem:

If $a+b+c=3 (a>0,b>0,c>0)$ then what is the greatest value of $a^2*b^3*c^2$.

(If I assume each one of them to be $1$,the greatest value also would equal $1$, but I'm not certain whether this answer is right.)

Comment: You didn't state your question properly. If $a+b+c=3 (a>0,b>0,c>0)$ then WHAT....? It's not clear what you are actually trying to proof.

Comment: Rewrite the condition as $\frac{a}{2}+\frac{a}{2}+\frac{b}{3}+\frac{b}{3}+\frac{b}{3}+\frac{c}{2}+\frac{c}{2} =3$  and apply the AM-GM inequality.

Comment: @cQQkie i corrected it.

Comment: @Nate Can you tell me how do i use the AM-GM inequality? I know that AMs are always greater than GMs but how do i use that relationship over here?

Comment: @Nate Thanks a lot Nate, i finally got the answers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to maximize the function $f(a,b,c)=a^2b^3c^2)$ subject to the constraints $a,b,c>0$ and $a+b+c=3$. This last constraint is the equation of a plane, and at the maximum, the gradient of the objective must be parallel to the normal of the plane. The gradient is:
$$ \nabla f = \{ 2ab^3c^2, 3a^2b^2c^2, 2a^2b^3c \}$$
and the normal to the plane is $\{1,1,1\}$, so we want:
$$ \nabla f = \lambda \{1,1,1\} $$
for some $\lambda$. Therefore, we can solve the following set of equations:
$$ 2ab^3c^2 = \lambda \\ 3a^2b^2c^2 = \lambda \\ 2a^2b^3c = \lambda \\ a+b+c=\lambda $$
This is essentially the method of Lagrange multipliers.

Hint: The solution for $a,b,c$ involves sevenths.

Comment: IS the answer 3^10*2^4/7^7 ?

Comment: Yes, that is the answer.